Fake Transactions

How do I find out if a transaction on bscscan is a fake transaction? I have looked at the information part of the website and it says if you see red it’s a fake transaction. Is that true or is there another way to find out if a transaction is legitimate.
When a transaction is registered on scan and in a wallet why can it be moved around to different wallet but can not be spendable?


Without screenshots, links or other context it is impossible to understand what you are talking about. Please edit the question to include more information.
